# Making Passive and Active NFC in Android

Tags: android, nfc

I want to use NFC for turnstile.I heard something for read turnstile my phone like card , phone must be passive NFC.Can I provide active and passive with codes?
Also here my codes that turnstile is reading sometimes.

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
        NfcAdapter.CreateNdefMessageCallback {

```
private NfcAdapter nfcAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);

    if (nfcAdapter == null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        nfcAdapter.setNdefPushMessageCallback(this, this);

    }
}

@Override
public NdefMessage createNdefMessage(NfcEvent nfcEvent) {
    NdefRecord ndefRecord = NdefRecord.createTextRecord("UTF-8",
            "1158979372850048");
    NdefRecord ndefRecord2 = NdefRecord.createTextRecord("UTF-8",
            "80 1b d2 e9 15 1e 04");
    NdefRecord ndefRecord3 = NdefRecord.createTextRecord("UTF-8",
            "36059389686521348");

    NdefRecord[] records = { ndefRecord3, ndefRecord2, ndefRecord };

    NdefMessage ndefMessage = new NdefMessage(records);
    return ndefMessage;

}
```

}

Can I make my phone's NFC passive with code?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that HCE(Host-based Card Emulation) technology is what you need:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/hce.html

https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/developing-android-business-apps-using-nfc-host-based-card-emulation-capabilities